# Bad sounding audio from a Sony SRS-X2 Bluetooth when connected to a Dell Inspiron laptop but fine via Android phones

Tags: laptop, audio, windows-10, bluetooth, speakers

I have a Sony SRS-X2 Bluetooth speaker and I’m trying to get it to work with my Dell Inspiron laptop running Windows 10. It works fine on the two Android phones that i have but when I connect it to my laptop the audio quality is bad and it seems to have a slight delay as well.

EDIT: I have an Dell Inspiron 15 5547 laptop.

The android phones that I've tried it on are a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime and Samsung Galaxy S4.